# Loop through array and echo all child arrays that have same ID

Tags: php, arrays

This is simplified version, I have an array filled with items and sometimes there could be duplicates

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'Item 1'
        ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'Item 2'
        ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'title' => 'Item 3'
        ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'Item 1'
        ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'title' => 'Item 1'
        ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'title' => 'Item 5'
        ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'title' => 'Item 1'
        ),
    );
?>
```

What I need is to go through each item and echo its title but if there are more items with same ID in array, I need to echo their title side by current item and skip them later.

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($items as $item) : ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $item['title']; ?> 
            <?php // check for other items and echo their titles if they are same
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

In the end, the example should come out like this

```
<li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3 Item 3 Item 3</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
```

Any thoughts on how to solve it without making a mess? :)

I was playing with stuff like this, somewhere echoes double lines.. generally not good

```
<?php $int = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($items as $item) : ?>
    <li>
        <?php 
        echo $item['title']; 
        $id = $item['id'];
        unset($items[$int]);
        $int++;

        foreach($items as $item_second) {
            if($item_second['id'] === $id) {
                echo $item_second['title'];
                unset($item_second);
            }
        }
        ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about preparing array before rendering into two dimensional array?
It will looks something like this:

```
<?php
    $itemsForRender = array();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (!isset($itemsForRender[$item['id']])) {
            $itemsForRender[$item['id']] = [];
        }

        $itemsForRender[$item['id']][] = $item['title'];
    }
?>
```

and after that just easily:

```
<?php foreach($itemsForRender as $items) : ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo implode(' ', $items); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hm hm.. I didnt't went that way because my example is fairly more complicated with more data and links... I would look for this solution as a plan B :)

Comment: What troubles are you met? Maybe I can help :-).

Comment: I will try to change my code tomorrow when I get some sleep so I don't mess something up, I will think more clearly :)